# Find date in a specific week

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to select an item where the date is in a specific week in the year.

For example :

```
SELECT item
FROM table
WHERE my_date in week 44
```

Where week 44 is from monday 31/10 to sunday 06/11.

I know to get the week number with

```
to_number(to_char(to_date(my_date,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'IW'))
```

How can I do that ?
Thanks.

Comment: If `my_date` is a `DATE` column, then the expression `to_date(my_date,'MM/DD/YYYY')` makes no sense at all. It converts the `DATE` to a varchar just to convert it back to `DATE` which it was to begin with. Never, ever call `to_date()` on values that are already a `date`

Comment: Regarding @a_horse_with_no_name's comment: What data type is the `my_date` column? Your composite function looks correct if it is a varchar2 (which it shouldn't be, it should be DATE datatype, but that kind of poor table design is very common, and often you must play the hand you were dealt).

Comment: my_date is a DATE, i can just do to_char(my_date, 'IW')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT item
FROM table
WHERE to_char( my_date, 'IW ) = '44'
```

See this link for details:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924

> **IW**    --->   Week of year (1-52 or 1-53) based on the ISO standard.

Answer (score 1):

Working with ISO Weeks is not trivial because week 1 can start in previous year and first days in January may be counted as week 52 or 53.

So, providing just week number without a year can be ambiguous (for week number 52, 53, 1).

The best function I found in order to get the first day of an ISO-Week is

```
NEXT_DAY(TO_DATE( yearNo || '0104', 'YYYYMMDD' ) - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'MONDAY') + ( weekNo - 1 ) * 7
```

So, for your need it would be

```
SELECT item
FROM table
WHERE my_date 
   between NEXT_DAY(TO_DATE( yearNo || '0104', 'YYYYMMDD' ) - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'MONDAY') + ( weekNo - 1 ) * 7
      AND 6 + (NEXT_DAY(TO_DATE( yearNo || '0104', 'YYYYMMDD' ) - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'MONDAY') + ( weekNo - 1 ) * 7)
```

Actually the "full error proven" way would be this one:

```
FUNCTION ISOWeekDate(weekNo INTEGER, yearNo INTEGER) RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC IS
    res DATE;
BEGIN
    IF weekNo > 53 OR weekNo < 1 THEN
        RAISE VALUE_ERROR;      
    END IF;
    res := NEXT_DAY(TO_DATE( yearNo || '0104', 'YYYYMMDD' ) - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'MONDAY') + ( weekNo - 1 ) * 7;
    IF TO_CHAR(res, 'fmIYYY') = yearNo THEN
        RETURN res;
    ELSE
        RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
    END IF;
END ISOWeekDate;
```

Comment: I would say working with ISO weeks is trivial (`trunc(dt, 'iw')`) - it's non-iso weeks that aren't trivial, due to the varying definitions they might have. ISO weeks are fixed, so ...

Answer (score 0):

If the data type of the `my_date` column is, in fact, VARCHAR2 (which it shouldn't be, but it often is), then you do need to convert it to date first, and then back to char (string) in a different format. Then, if 44 is not necessarily a number but it may be the result of a calculation, or a subquery, or a value in another table (and if it is of NUMBER data type), then you need to do exactly what you were doing. What was the problem with it?

```
select item
from   your_table
where  to_number(to_char(to_date(my_date,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'IW')) = 44;
```

Perhaps you want to know if this can be done more efficiently? So, for example, can you instead write the `where` condition as

```
my_date between (something) and (something else)
```

which would allow the use of an index on `my_date`? The answer is NO, if `my_date` is in VARCHAR2 format - you would still have to wrap it within `to_date()` so you would lose the index.

But, you may build an index function on `to_date(my_date)` which perhaps would help you in other queries as well. So then the question of making your present query more efficient is meaningful. Now you run into the complication of ISO week not being well defined (you are not also saying which YEAR), so the assumption is that you want the date to be in ISO week 44 of whatever year it is in. If the date is a pure date (time component equal to 00:00:00), you could do this:

```
where to_date(my_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') between 
          trunc(sysdate, 'iw') + 7 * (44 - to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'iw')))     and
          trunc(sysdate, 'iw') + 7 * (44 - to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'iw'))) + 6
```

There are a lot of computation on the right-hand side, but they are done just once for all the rows in your table; they will take essentially no time at all.